# Issues with mypy, compose method and duplicated code

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I've tried looking for answers to this, as I can't possibly be the first one to stumble across this issue, but my google-fu is failing me terribly.

Is it possible to make `mypy` understand that certain functions/methods are only meant to be called from within another method?

Let's take the following code as example (E: for clarity - this is a simplified, runnable version of a real-life problem that involves a Django model instance that has an intentionally nullable field):

```
from typing import Optional


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        self.value = value


def compose_method(foo: Foo) -> None:
    if not foo.value:
        raise RuntimeError("Oh no!")

    __method_1(foo)
    __method_2(foo)


def __method_1(foo: Foo) -> None:
    foo.value + 1


def __method_2(foo: Foo) -> None:
    foo.value + 2
```

Running `mypy` on this file unsurprisingly results in:

```
test_mypy.py:18: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")
test_mypy.py:18: note: Left operand is of type "Optional[int]"
test_mypy.py:22: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")
test_mypy.py:22: note: Left operand is of type "Optional[int]"
```

It's obviously right, but it doesn't take into account the fact that the methods are only intended to be called from within `compose_method` - which already has checked that `value != None`. I don't want to duplicate code and put the `if not foo.value:` condition in each method where `foo.value` is used just to satisfy the tooling. At the same time, putting `# type: ignore` also doesn't quite sit right with me.

Is there some best practice/way to handle this that the community has agreed is good and right? Or am I just doomed to duplicate the code (and sure, the check can be put in a separate method and called in each of the methods that `compose_method` consists of) or use `# type: ignore` comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write things such that `__method_1` and `__method_2` are only called from within `compose_method` but, for all mypy knows, someone will import your file and calls those methods directly.  Remember that Python doesn't really have a concept of private items.

What you can do is squash the error by telling mypy, in essence, "I promise that `value` isn't `None` here," by using `typing.cast`.

```py
def __method_1(foo: Foo) -> None:
    foo.value = typing.cast(int, foo.value) + 1
```

There is a **slight** performance hit here.  Since this doesn't use `+=`, the Python compiler doesn't emit the `INPLACE_ADD` byte code.  I originally thought to do instead `typing.cast(int, foo.value) += 1`.  However, with the function call, it's no longer an L-value and therefore becomes invalid syntax.

Because of that, the best thing to do may just be the `# type: ignore`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Using `typing.cast` might indeed be a solution for the real life case, you're a boss :)

Tangentially, this makes me wonder if having a decorator a'la `@mypy.only_called_from('name_of_function', 'name_of_function_2')` to handle such cases could be useful in mypy - though I expect there to be objections (and for good reaon). I might try and bring it up with the dev/contributor team directly on GH (though first I'd have to go through 70+ pages of issues to make sure I'm not duplicating anything :D)

Comment: Also: `def __method_2(foo: Foo) -> None:  assert isinstance(foo.value, int);  foo.value + 2` can work. And assert disappears when code is run with  `-O` param.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `assert`, the advantage is that `assert` disappears when python is started with the `-O` option.

```
from typing import Optional


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        self.value = value


def compose_method(foo: Foo) -> None:
    if not foo.value:
        raise RuntimeError("Oh no!")

    __method_1(foo)
    __method_2(foo)


def __method_1(foo: Foo) -> None:
    assert isinstance(foo.value, int)  
    foo.value + 1


def __method_2(foo: Foo) -> None:
    assert isinstance(foo.value, int)  
    foo.value + 2
```

Comment: You are correct, but the presented solution still requires duplicating code.

Comment: Perhaps a function: `def addfoo(foo: Foo, x:int) -> None:  assert isinstance(foo.value, int)
 foo.value + x`. You can pass also an operator to make it more general. And i also must say that assert is duplicated but disappear using `-O` .